# Bringing the other column , along all with all the other columns of the table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to Bringing the other column , along all with all the other columns of the table (Oracle)

As shown below

```
select order_id,person_id,col4,col5,* from orders
```

It is giving the below error :

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 66
```

Any inputs would be helpful !!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why listing individual columns and then * in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias:

```
select col1, col2, c.*
from my_table c
```

Comment: @user1993412 The alias is a table alias.  So your query would be: select order_id, person_id, col4, col5, o.* from orders o

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify columns together * wild card in Oracle, try if possible with alias

```
select order_id as A,person_id  as B,col4  as C,col5  as D,* from orders
```

Comment: Nope , it does not . ORA-00904: "ORD": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 106

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify columns and the use a wildcard on the same query when doing a SQL SELECT.

This is due to [*projections*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12619/what-does-the-term-projection-refer-to-in-an-sql-query-or-view-definition) and (as in relational algebra) projections requires that you specify attributes for selection.

In order to fully use projections, you either set attribute names and use alias (if you want to use wildcards).

Comment: This is incorrect.  Try this:  select owner, o.* from dba_objects o